# How to find Backpack version (Laravel)

Tags: laravel-backpack

How do I know which backpack version my project uses pls?
Is there a command line or do I need to look into a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can run `php artisan backpack:version`. Alternatively, if that doesn't work, you can use `composer show |grep backpack/crud`

Comment: I am getting - Command "backpack:version" is not defined.  
                                              
  Did you mean one of these?                  
      backpack:base:install                   
      backpack:config                         
      backpack:crud                           
      backpack:crud-controller                
      backpack:crud-model                     
      backpack:crud-request                   
      backpack:model.... Is this supposed to work for older versions too?

Comment: Ah, ok, that means you must have a pretty old version - we introduced that command a few years ago. I've edited my answer above - in that case you can do `composer show |grep backpack/crud`